# Do you know if i can integrate with as3isolib some physic engine like nape or box2d?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

i just searching for any resource that explain or teach how integrate if it possible as3isolib with some physics engine like, nape or box2d. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that.
For example Box2D Body has member userData, which type is *, so you can assign any data there.
As far as Box2D and nape are 2D physics engines, you can make 2d phys modifications on x and y axis.
Here is an example:

```
package 
{
    import as3isolib.display.primitive.IsoBox;
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoScene;

    import Box2D.Dynamics.Contacts.*;
    import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
    import Box2D.Collision.*;
    import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
    import Box2D.Common.Math.*;
    import Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.*;


    import flash.events.Event;

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var scene:IsoScene;
        private var world:b2World;
        private var gravity:b2Vec2;
        private var body:b2Body;
        private const worldScale:int = 30;
        private const doSleep:Boolean = true;
        private static const m_iterations:int = 10;
        private static const m_timeStep:Number = 1.0/30.0;


        public function Main ()
        {
            scene = new IsoScene();
            scene.hostContainer = this;

            var bodyDef:b2BodyDef;
            var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();

            gravity = new b2Vec2(0.0, 4.0);
            world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);

            bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
            bodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
            bodyDef.allowSleep = false;
            bodyDef.linearDamping = 1;
            bodyDef.angularDamping = 1;
            bodyDef.position.x = 200/worldScale; //position
            bodyDef.position.y = 100/worldScale; //position
            bodyDef.userData = new IsoBox();
            bodyDef.userData.setSize(25, 25, 25);
            bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.5;
            fixtureDef.shape = new b2CircleShape(0.3);
            fixtureDef.density = 1;
            fixtureDef.friction = 5;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.5;

            scene.addChild(bodyDef.userData);

            body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
            body.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
        }

        private function Update(e:Event):void
        {
            world.Step(m_timeStep, m_iterations, m_iterations);
            world.ClearForces();
            body.GetUserData().moveTo(body.GetPosition().x * worldScale, body.GetPosition().y * worldScale, 0);

            scene.render();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need more complex tutorial, i can write some article.

Comment: I will try with this example and write you back. There are some difference between nape and box2d? i mean, the better is? I really appreciated your help.

Comment: nape is more optimized, but it has pure docs and most of examples in haXe. Box2D has a lot of examples, tutorials, but it slow on scenes with many objects. If you are not familiar with as3, i'd suggest you to use Box2d.

Comment: i'm familiar with as3, if you recommend me nape i'll try it with nape.

Comment: http://ubuntuone.com/6O6LjOJwRW7zGuoA3UrTrY here is archive with needed libraries and example code included. just make mxmlc Main.as -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true

Comment: For my current project i chose nape. So i recommend it. Integration with as3isolib is like Box2D example.

Comment: this thing really was driving me crazy, thanks so much really thanks! :p

Comment: Hey, sorry if i am a little annoying, when i put in userData the IsoSprite Object return _Cannot create property rotation on as3isolib.display.IsoSprite_

Comment: I'am trying to do something more simply because it seem that with isolib is a little more complex for me. Im using now just nape to do some boxes and i need to add some listeners to every box, i'm in that because i don't understand clearly the callbacks.

`_space.listeners.add(new BodyListener(CbEvent.WAKE,  boxcb, boxer(0x00ff00)));
`
http://pastebin.com/s4yah3aF

Comment: _space.listeners.add(new BodyListener(CbEvent.WAKE, boxcb, boxer));
private function boxer(body:Body):void { your stuff here }
That's about callbacks. You should pass just name of handler function and it will get body as param.

Comment: should i look to pastebin.com/s4yah3aF ?
What exactly wrong with it? I will try to deal with it tomorrow.

Comment: The last one is only an example with just nape. You have some chat contact?